# Gateaux and Frechet derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: derivatives, banach-spaces, gateaux-derivative

I have the following problem:

*Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:*

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)= \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}, \quad x \neq 0, y\neq 0
\end{equation}
*and:* 
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=0, \quad x=0,y=0
\end{equation}
*Show that $f$ is* **Gateaux differentiable** *at $0$ and the* **Gateaux derivative** *at that point is $0$*.
*Moreover, show that $f$ is not* **Frechet differentiable** *at $(0,0)$.*

These concepts of differentiability are new to me, therefore all I need is a detailed way of proving what this problem asks for. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(u,v)\neq(0,0)$.

$D_{(0,0)}f(u,v)=\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\dfrac{f\big((0,0)+\epsilon((u,v))\big)-f(0,0)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\dfrac{f(\epsilon u,\epsilon v)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\dfrac{\epsilon^4 u^3v}{\epsilon(\epsilon^4 u^4+\epsilon^2 v^2)}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\dfrac{\epsilon^4}{\epsilon\cdot\epsilon^2}\left[\dfrac{u^3v}{\epsilon^2 u^4+v^2}\right]=0$

(Note that if $(u,v)=(0,0)$ we obtain the same)

Then, $D_{(0,0)}f=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$.

But $f$ cannot be Fréchet differentiable because has a removable discontinuity at $(0, 0)$ (one can see by approaching the origin along the curve (t,t)).

Comment: Thank you so much! But how to also prove the Frechet issue you mention? I know it is simple but it's my first steps so I am not really sure what to do..

Comment: I just follow the definition that I found on mathworld:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GateauxDerivative.html
 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrechetDerivative.html